# Trouble editing json

Tags: javascript, json

This is the current json i have:

```
var _cartInfo;
var _cart = localStorage.getItem("w3lssbmincart");
_cart = decodeURIComponent(_cart);
_cart = JSON.parse(_cart);
```

_cart returns:

```
{
    "value": {
        "items": [{
            "cmd": "_cart",
            "add": "1",
            "w3ls_item": "MIXZA  TOHAOLL 128GB",
            "amount": 52.53,
            "quantity": 1,
            "href": "localhost:27524/Home.aspx"
        }, {
            "cmd": "_cart",
            "add": "1",
            "w3ls_item": "Huawei 1",
            "amount": 0.99,
            "quantity": 2,
            "href": "localhost:27524/Telemovel.aspx"
        }, {
            "cmd": "_cart",
            "add": "1",
            "w3ls_item": "Apple 1",
            "amount": 1.09,
            "quantity": 1,
            "href": "localhost:27524/"
        }],
        "settings": {
            "bn": "sbmincart_AddToCart_WPS_US"
        }
    },
    "expires": "Thu, 27 Jul 2017 17:07:45 GMT"
}
```

How do i make it so that the variable holds only the items like this:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "cmd": "_cart",
        "add": "1",
        "w3ls_item": "MIXZA  TOHAOLL 128GB",
        "amount": 52.53,
        "quantity": 1,
        "href": "localhost:27524/Home.aspx"
    }, {
        "cmd": "_cart",
        "add": "1",
        "w3ls_item": "Huawei 1",
        "amount": 0.99,
        "quantity": 2,
        "href": "localhost:27524/Telemovel.aspx"
    }, {
        "cmd": "_cart",
        "add": "1",
        "w3ls_item": "Apple 1",
        "amount": 1.09,
        "quantity": 1,
        "href": "localhost:27524/"
    }]
}
```

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: What do you don't need `_cart = decodeURIComponent(_cart);` for ?

Comment: `_cart = _cart.value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var _newCart = {};
_newCart['items'] = _cart['value']['items'];
```